# Using Ambari with Non-HDP components

Tags: rest, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I was trying to figure out if we can use Ambari with Non-HDP components or services like ElasticSearch or Tomcat or something like that. I read that Ambari interfaces with the supported components using RESTful APIs. Can something similar be done with other services like the ones I have mentioned? Has anyone done that? If so, how it was done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Ambari Stacks](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38571133#Overview(Ambari1.5.0orlater)-Example:ImplementingaCustomClientService) (since 1.5.0 or later) can manage custom services.

Comment: Wanna take a stab at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419487/ambari-unsupported-or-invalid-service-in-stack