# Ambari - Unsupported or invalid service in stack

Tags: rest, hadoop, centos, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to install a custom service using [these instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38571133#Overview%28Ambari1.5.0orlater%29-Example:ImplementingaCustomClientService) and [these commands](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Adding+a+New+Service+to+an+Existing+Cluster) to add the service. When I issue the curl command, instead of getting added, I get this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Set-Cookie: AMBARISESSIONID=ID;Path=/
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 139
Server: Jetty(7.6.7.v20120910)

{
"status" : 400,
"message" : "Unsupported or invalid service in stack, clusterName=MahiMahi, serviceName=TESTSRV, stackInfo=HDP-2.1"
}
```

What is going on here? My cluster is installed perfectly and I can see the dashboard and metrics and stuff. Just can’t seem to add a custom service. Please help out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. When using Ambari 1.6.1, it automatically downloads and uses HDP 2.1. The folder structure in the link says: `cd /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services`. I changed it to: `cd /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.1/services`. Problem solved. So stupid. So simple. So much frustration. Such hopeless documentation.